# Simple CSS Layout Wrapping Images in IE but not FF or Chrome

Tags: html, css

I have a very simple layout that doesn't look correct in Ie.  I've messed with Firebug Lite and the IE Developer Toolbar but just can't seem to boil down why the right image wraps way below the left image in this case.
Here is a link to the problem that I've simplified for debugging purposes.
http://tunetra.de/test/layout.html

I'll also past my HTML here below.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#container
{
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 1000px;
    background: #fff;
}

#main
{
  text-align: left;
}
</style>
</head>
<body style="text-align:center;">
  <div id="container">
    <div id="header">
      <img src="img/left_image.png" style="width: 272px; height: 90px; float: left;position: relative;"> 
      <div style="float: right;position: relative;background-color: #fff;width: 728px;height: 90px;">
      <img src="img/right_image.png" style="">
    </div>
  </div>     
  <div id="main">
    Lorem Ipsum Bla<br/> Bla<br/> Bla
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what's the problem. your left image is at left side and right image at right side. what you want.?

Comment: Check in IE, the right image seems to be like 7 or 8 pixels too big therefore is shifted below the left image.

Comment: As @JonathanSampson alludes to, you might want to note **which** version(s) of IE you mean.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your page works just fine by default in Internet Explorer 10. I do see the problem you're alluding to in Internet Explorer 9 though. This is caused by your page loading in Quirks Mode. Insert the following Doctype to correct this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Place that just before `<html>` on the first line. This resolves your issue.

You can quickly test this by putting your page into Standards Mode using the F12 Developer Tools. Press F12 on your keyboard to reveal the Developer Tools. At the top-right, click "Document Mode: Quirks Mode" and change it to "Internet Explorer 9 Standards".

Comment: Thank you very much.  The quirks mode thing was the issue.  As soon as I added your suggestion it worked fine in IE9 (the version I was testing).  Thanks!